# Accessory view on UITextField

Tags: swift, button, passwords

I created a textfield and a button for the eye.
The privacy eye is superimposed on the password when it reaches more than 35 characters.
Do you have any idea how to solve this problem? here is my code for the button

[image]

```
public var pincodeVisibilityButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.setTitleColor(.SEBlack, for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.icon(ofSize: 34)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    return button
}()
```

Comment: It looks like a constraint issue. The trailing edge of your textfield should go to the leading edge of your button

Comment: Adding the button as the `UITextField`'s `rightView` is a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

It is best to use built in functionality.

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield

Sample code is below:

```
let overlayButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
let bookmarkImage = UIImage(systemName: "bookmark")
overlayButton.setImage(bookmarkImage, for: .normal)
overlayButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(displayBookmarks), 
    for: .touchUpInside)
overlayButton.sizeToFit()
        
// Assign the overlay button to the text field
textField.rightView = overlayButton
textField.rightViewMode = .always
```

Refer: